# C# escape characters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++) {
    s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + \t + speakerID[i]);
}
```

I'm trying to get a tab character in-between speakerAmt[i] and speakerID[i].
Do escape characters need to be in " **" "** " (quotation marks)?

EDIT: Thank you! in less than 50 seconds, I had about 5 answers.  I'm impressed!

Comment: Yes/No.  I did put it into quotes , and the error line went away, but I didn't build. Its a very, very, big program

Comment: @wizlog: That would be a "No".  As a hint, if you have a small thing that you aren't sure of but don't want to build/execute a large application: Just create a quick and dirty winforms app and try it there.  Shouldn't have taken more than about 60 seconds to determine the answer start to finish.

Comment: I recommend [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test small code snippets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
    s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
}
```

And It's better to do following

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
    s.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}",speakerAmt[i],speakerID[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1: Not because you answered an excruciatingly simple question.  Rather because maybe the OP will be exposed to the String.Format routine.. ;)

Comment: Since C#6, you can use string interpolation: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855981/1248177)

Answer (score 5):

escape characters are characters, therefore they needs to be in single quotes `'\t'`. Or you can construct a string with one escape character which makes it `"\t"` . Without any quotes `\t` is illegal.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
    s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the quotes are necessary.

```
s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
```

Why it is necessary:

Because this is an escape sequence that is part of a string. `\t` is . Like:

```
var hi = "Hello\tWorld";
```

The compiler just interprets this in a special manner when used in the context of a string. The `\` character in a string usually denotes the beginning of an escape sequence (exception: string literals). Here is another example that also uses a tab using a different way:

```
var hi = "Hello\u0009World";
```

You can read more about strings, literals, and escape sequences as part of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Yes they do

```
string str = "Hello\tWorld!\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you need to do this:

```
 s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they need to be in a string

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
   s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup!

```
for (int i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
   s.WriteLine(speakerAmt[i] + "\t" + speakerID[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since C#6, it is even better to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < speaker.Length; i++)
{
    s.WriteLine($"{speakerAmt[i]}\t{speakerID[i]}");
}
```

It is [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)